# default values not working same on creation and updation - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have model **`user.rb`** like below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

before_save :set_default

    def set_default
        self[:is_admin] || 0 
        self[:is_active] || 1   
    end 
end
```

Now when i create u new user , it inserts `is_admin = null` , `is_active = null` . While when i update user and send parameters `is_admin= true` , `is_active = true` or whatever values it updates it correctly . I did some R&D and found that i should do the following

```
def set_default
        self.is_admin || 0 
        self.is_active || 1   
end
```

Now the case becomes totally alternate . Means now values are inserting correctly on creation . but updation makes no difference . I also tried it with the following

```
def set_default
        self.is_admin ||= 0 
        self.is_active ||= 1   
end
```

But still no help . Kindly explain what's going on . Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: hey I've never seen that syntax before! `self.is_admin]` can you tell me what that square bracket does? and what should i google to get more info on that?

Comment: @Harfangk it's not syntactically valid Ruby actually. So... nothing :)

Answer (score 1):

If you always want those fields to start with that default data, I would move your defaults to the schema.

```
def change
  create_table :users do |t|
    t.boolean :is_admin, default: false, null: false
    t.boolean :is_active, default: true, null: false
    ...
  end
end
```

This will set the defaults on your `users` table without needing the extra cost/complication of a callback. This will also nicely blow up if you try to set either of those to `nil` which would produce unexpected behaviors in your application.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the typo j-dexx :)

Comment: voted for the fix , but dear i think that's not the solution . I mean why that odd behaviour

Comment: Can you clarify a little? If it sets it properly on creation, then updating it would disregard both of those statements because `||=` would only ever set those values if they are `nil`. Not sure if thats what you are asking though.